# Is there any way to reorder execution order for output assignment in simulink?

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

im trying to generate C-code from a simulink model. I'm trying to grep some signals "in the middle of the code" to redirect that data to have access to that data during codegeneration. But the execution order of the generated code is not as I need it.

See this picture as example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/44zgpxdlwjvvbzo/Current.PNG?dl=0)

This generates the following code:

```
...
real_T rtb_Add1;
real_T rtb_Add;
rtb_Add = Test1_U.In1 + Test1_U.In2;
rtb_Add1 = rtb_Add + Test1_U.In2;
Test1_Y.Out1 = rtb_Add1;
Test1_Y.Out2 = Test1_U.In1;
Test1_Y.Out3 = rtb_Add;
Test1_Y.Out4 = rtb_Add1;
...
```

But what I need to achive is an execution order like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jf8p6hk58z691so/Required.png?dl=0

such that the generated code looks like this:

```
...
real_T rtb_Add1;
real_T rtb_Add;
Test1_Y.Out2 = Test1_U.In1;
rtb_Add = Test1_U.In1 + Test1_U.In2;
Test1_Y.Out3 = rtb_Add;
rtb_Add1 = rtb_Add + Test1_U.In2;
Test1_Y.Out4 = rtb_Add1;
Test1_Y.Out1 = rtb_Add1;
...
```

I already tried to adapt priorities of the blocks, but it seems that I have no option to set some priority to atomic subsystems.
Do you have any idea whether its possible to manipulate the execution order of the model such that the required code is achieved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you had a read of https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/controlling-and-displaying-the-sorted-order.html?

Comment: yeah I've already skimmed over that link.. But thanks for making me to read it again :D
I've found that I indeed can asign a priority to atomic subsystems!
Unfortunately the last 2 options including the properties option disappeared from my too small screen..